# Validation does not work in IE11 and Edge

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've used Chrome for debugging while I was developing my website and jQuery validation worked successfully. However it doesn't work IE11 and Edge. I don't know what the problem is. I used the newest version of jQuery, jquery.validate from CDN, and programmed server using 'flask'(Python), jinja2 web template. What is causing the problem?

Here's a simplified example of the source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        onkeyup:false,
        onclick:false,
        onfocusout:false,
        showErrors:function(errorMap, errorList){
            if(this.numberOfInvalids()) {
                $(errorList[0].element).focus();
                errorList[0].element.setCustomValidity(errorList[0].message);
                errorList[0].element.addEventListener('invalid', function(){}, true);
                errorList[0].element.reportValidity();
            }
        }
    });

    $("#signup").validate({
        rules:{
            id:{required:true, rangelength:[5,10]},
            pwd:{required:true, rangelength:[5,15]},
            pwdConfirm:{required:true, equalTo:"#pwd"}
        },
        messages:{
            id:{
                required:"msg...",
                rangelength:"msg..."
            },
            pwd:{
                required:"msg...",
                rangelength:"msg..."
            },
            pwdConfirm:{
                required:"msg...",
                equalTo:"msg..."
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<form class="uk-form uk-form-stacked" id="signup" role="form" name="signup" method="post" action="{{url_for('signup')}}" autocomplete="off">
    <input name="id" id="id" type="text" placeholder="Please enter username">
    <input name="pwd" id="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Please enter password">
    <input name="pwdConfirm" id="pwdConfirm" type="password" placeholder="Please confirm password">
</form>
```

- edit1, 
  Here is my code in jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/wjjzyxdx/3/

but it doesn't work even in Chrome, I don't know what is the problem.

So, I tried to test in next link, http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_rangeOverflow

First, I deleted w3shools example code, and then I copied and pasted my source code into text area. It works in Chrome, but it still doesn't work in Explorer and Edge browser.

- edit2, I found it, 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity

I think this problem is due to reportValidity(), it doesn't support other browser except chrome,

So I wonder that what is replaced with this reportValidity function.

Comment: hit `f12` and see if this version of IE is actually not emulated on `7,8`.

Comment: FYI - according the official website, the jQuery Validate plugin was only tested with jQuery up through version 1.11.1 - try that instead and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Jai, the OP never said anything about using emulation or versions 7, 8.  However, the OP should know that Explorer's "compatibility mode" is **not** true browser emulation... it's just a fallback for inadequate code that's not up to date.

Comment: Note that `reportValidity()` has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Since you're using jQuery Validate and it includes a bunch of useful methods, and guaranteed to work cross-browser, why would you want to use some obscure JavaScript method that's only supported in Chrome?

Comment: @Sparky obscure JavaScript method? You've got this all backwards- why would you use jQuery to do form validation when the latter is part of the living HTML 5 standard? And it's hardly "only supported in Chrome" - https://caniuse.com/#feat=constraint-validation

Comment: @Madbreaks, in context, my comment was directed at the OP who stated that this method *"doesn't support other browser except chrome"*.  Either use the jQuery plugin or use pure JavaScript... in this case, the OP is asking about a problem with jQuery that he is causing himself.  If he simply removes the JavaScript method he's complaining about, the plugin would work fine.